# Запрос на сайт, требующий js

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

Я делаю запрос на сайт:

```
request('http://example.com' function (error, response, body) {
  console.error('error:', error);
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
  console.log('body:' body);
});
```

который требует чтобы JS был включен. Как включить или имитировать включение JS при запросе? На сколько я понимаю, здесь могут помочь headers, но вот только я не понял как ими пользоваться

Comment: Возможно, вам нужен документ с содержимым, которое генерируется скриптами, тогда вам придётся воспользоваться одной из библиотек, управляющих браузерами или их эмуляциями. Например, https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt Да, я пытаюсь получить содержимое, которое генерируется с помощью скриптов, конкретнее я пытаюсь получить html код страницы в твиттере. Я попробовал вот такой код: 
`const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://twitter.com/Cybersole');
  var HTML = await page.content()
  console.log(HTML);
})();`
Но он не работает, вернее страница открывается, но в html коде написано, что JS отключён и поэтому html не тот.
Не подскажите, почему такое может быть?

Comment: Не могу воспроизвести проблему. Да, код страницы всё равно содержит теги noscript с предупреждением об отключённом JavaScript, но их содержит и страница в обычном браузере, просто они не отображаются. Проверьте поиском по коду текст какого-нибудь твита — у меня твиты включены в код.

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt Да, действительно, я добавил небольшую задержку и теперь получаю нормальный html код. Мне нужно проверять, появились ли какие-то изменения на странице. Для этого я так понимаю мне нужен таймер, но вот если в таймер запихнуть код который я написал в первом коментарии, то будет открыватся  слишком много браузеров(даже если закрвать с помощью browser.close()), то есть мне нужно разбить тот код, и только часть отвечающую за переход на страницу, её парсинг и закрытие оставить в таймере, но как разбить код, если строчки кода содержат "await"? Или лучше делать проверку по другому?

Comment: Мне трудно понять вашу методику) Насколько я помню, новые твиты подгружаются автоматически (или появляется уведомление о новых твитах в начале ленты). Чтобы фиксировать изменения, достаточно просто мониторить какой-то селектор и его содержимое. Для этого можно использовать, например, `page.waitForFunction()` - и сравнивать или содержимое первого твита с текущим, или ссылку на него. Возможно, стоит вставить прокрутку чуть вниз и опять вверх, чтобы твиты подгрузились.

Comment: Если под таймером вы понимаете классический таймер с колбеком, то его можно заменить на бесконечный цикл с `await page.waitFor()`, например.

Comment: В том то и проблема, что пока страницу не обновишь — не узнаешь, появился новый твит или нет. Хотя в html коде можно найти span в котором написано "Посмотреть новые твиты", но он всегда скрыт, даже когда появляется новый твит.

Comment: Ну, тогда вам достаточно запустить бесконечный цикл, а в нём ждать какое-то время при помощи `await page.waitFor()`, переоткрывать тот же адрес и сравнивать первый твит по содержимому или идентификатору (например, ссылке на твит), сохраняя содержимое или идентификатор, если они поменялись, для новых итераций.

Comment: Только не злоупотребляйте с частотой, иначе сервер может вас забанить.

Comment: Если вам нужны твиты, почему бы не работать с АПИ твитера напрямую? Зачем вам прослойка из браузера? Проанализируйте, какие запросы уходят для получения твитов и делайте такие же запросы со своего сервера.